# Form required text field (Mailer,Flutter)

Tags: flutter, mailer

I explain to you I am trying at the moment making it compulsory to fill in information sending the information sent via mailer.

If it is possible to have an explanation so that I understand how adding the code to my form works.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Demande'),
  ),
  body: Container(
    color: Color(0xffd8edff),
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Card(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: nomController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Nom:',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: prenomController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Prénom:',
                    ),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: emailController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'E-mail:',
                      hintText: 'Ex: john.wilson@domain.gov',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      barrierDismissible: false,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        // return object of type Dialog
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to wrap your entire form with a `Form` widget.

You can then pass a `GlobalKey<FormState>` into the `Form` to get a reference to it that you can use in other methods

You should create your form key in the `initState()` of your `State` class (make sure you are using a `StatefulWidget`).

Once you have done this, you can pass a `validator` to your `TextFormField`s. The `validator` takes a string, and returns `null` if the input is valid, or an error message string if the input is invalid.

Then, on the submit button, you can call `formKey.currentState.validate()`. This method returns `false` if any text field failed its validator.

For example:

```dart
GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey;


@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _formKey = GlobalKey();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(key: _formKey, child: Column(
        children: [
            TextFormField(
                validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) return 'Please enter a value';
                    else return null;
                },
                controller: ...  // whatever controller you are using
            ),
            FlatButton(
                child: Text('Submit'),
                onPressed: () {
                    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                      //  if this returns true, all the text fields have got good data (i.e. all fields are non-empty)
                      doSomething();
                    } else {
                      // if the call to validate() returns false, the error messages will appear automatically.
                      // you can run any extra code you need here
                    }
                }
            )
        ]
    ));
}
```